# mysql error when backing up a database that has views

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I back up a database (Structure and Data)
Options Checked:
CREATE DATABASE before copying
Add AUTO_INCREMENT value

it fails if the database has a view in it. I do not get this error backing up any other databases.

Here is Error message. I do not know what #1050 is in the MYSQL documentation:

> SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> CREATE TABLE `vw_MediaOutlets-lk-ClientForContact` (
>
> `fk_client_id` INT( 11 ) , `id` INT( 11 ) , `outlet_name` TEXT,
> `outlet_subjects` TEXT, `email` TEXT, `circulation` TEXT,
> `contact_title` TEXT, `city` TEXT, `state` TEXT );
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1050 - Table 'vw_MediaOutlets-lk-ClientForContact' already exists

And then the result is an empty copied database.

I am using phpMyAdmin version 4.0.5
and mysql version 5.1.70-cll
on a shared hosted server

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem with version 4.0.5. Did the target database exist before the copy?

Comment: No, I made up a totally new database name. I am thinking it is my version oh phpmyadmin if it works for you.

Comment: I also tested with version 4.0.5. For a better test, I would need the structure of your database.

Comment: I've seen this before but have no solution (except to kill all the seemingly useless "Stand-in structure for view" table creation spots & then grab my DB code that creates the views and create them after the import). This article might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573720/mysql-stand-in-structure-for-view-what-is-it