# Error while using Stand-in structure for view

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to import an sql file into phpmyadmin. Whenever I am using "Stand-in structure for view" with a table without any columns , I am getting 1064 error.
Here's the code snippet.`--

```
-- Stand-in structure for view `conflict_rooms`
--
CREATE TABLE `conflict_rooms` (
);
```

If there is at least one column (i.e. attribute) inside that table, then it's working fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573720/mysql-stand-in-structure-for-view-what-is-it

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey I know what it is for, my question is why the above code snippet fails.

Comment: Because it's invalid SQL.  (as Gordon points out, correctly, below).

Comment: But it worked on other systems. It's actually an old sql file which my seniors worked on. Probably in the latest versions empty tables are not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is.  Tables contain columns.  It has been a long time SQL requirement that tables have at least one column.  I would recommend:

```
CREATE TABLE `conflict_rooms` (
    conflict_rooms_id int auto_increment primary key
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573720/mysql-stand-in-structure-for-view-what-is-it

Comment: @Gordon it's a very large sql file of around 100000 lines, and i cant add a column for each of them. Is there any where to fix that.

Comment: @KingC . . . If someone wrote 100,000 lines of code without testing any of it, then you probably have more problems than these statements.